# Query regarding Concatenation

Tags: prolog

I know that we can concat atoms using `atom_concat(Para1,Para1,Final).`, Is there any function available in Prolog which can perform the reverse operation  mean it takes input as an atom and provides two atom in which one is the last character of the atom and second is remaining one. eg.

`?- rev_atom_concat(likes,Para1,Para2).

Para1 = like, Para2 = s`

I am not sure that is this really possible or not..?

Comment: @larsmans: Thanks, I was not aware with that issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [sub_atom](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%274.20%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/manipatom.html%27%29%29#sub_atom/5) for this. sub_atom extracts part of an atom. The syntax is:

```
sub_atom(+Atom, ?Before, ?Len, ?After, ?Sub)
```

Atom is the initial atom; Sub the sub-atom. Extraction works this way:

```
<************************ Atom ************************>
<***** Prefix *****><***** Sub *****><**** Suffix *****>
<-- before chars --><-- len chars --><-- after chars -->
```

For example, to extract the last character:

```
?- sub_atom(likes, _, 1, 0, S).
S = s.
```

For exemple, to extract all the characters but the last one:

```
?- sub_atom(likes, 0, _, 1, S).
S = like.
```